# Two instances of a singleton bean is created by SpringBoot, causing application to fail

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, dependency-injection

I have a Gradle project, where we are using following versions.

```
buildscript {

    ext {

    /* Plugin versions */
    openApiGeneratorVersion = "6.6.0"
    openApiMergerPluginVersion = "1.0.5"
    aspectjPluginVersion = "8.0.1"
    springBootVersion = "2.5.15"
    springBootDependencyManagementVersion = "1.0.15.RELEASE"

    /* Jar versions */
    sshjVersion = "0.35.0"
    workflowEngineBuildType = "bora"
    workflowEngineVersion = "21917453"
    lombokVersion = "1.18.24"
    aspectjrtVersion = "1.9.19"
    swaggerCoreVersion = "2.2.12"
    junitVersion = "5.8.1"

    }
}
```

The build creates executable Jar file.

```
bootJar {
    manifest {
        attributes 'Start-Class': 'com.xxx.xxx.xxx.StartClass'
    }
}
```

I have declared bean

```
@Component
public class VMForgeTopologyFacade implements VmForgeTopologyApiDelegate
```

The Startup of application is failing due to

> 2023-06-25 19:37:05.840  WARN 22817 --- [           main]
> ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered
> during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt:
> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
> Error creating bean with name 'vmForgeTopologyApiController' defined
> in URL
> [jar:file:/Users/sagarg/vmware/vm-forge/build/libs/vmforge-0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/vm-forge-api-0.1.jar!/com/vmware/vmforge/api/VmForgeTopologyApiController.class]:
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0;
> nested exception is
> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No
> qualifying bean of type
> 'com.vmware.vmforge.api.VmForgeTopologyApiDelegate' available:
> expected single matching bean but found 2:
> VMForgeTopologyFacade,com.vmware.vmforge.api.topology.facade.VMForgeTopologyFacade
>
> *************************** APPLICATION FAILED TO START
>
> ---
>
> Description:
>
> Parameter 0 of constructor in
> com.vmware.vmforge.api.VmForgeTopologyApiController required a single
> bean, but 2 were found:
>
> - VMForgeTopologyFacade: defined in URL [jar:file:/Users/sagarg/vmware/vm-forge/build/libs/vmforge-0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/vm-forge-api-service-0.1.jar!/com/vmware/vmforge/api/topology/facade/VMForgeTopologyFacade.class]
> - com.vmware.vmforge.api.topology.facade.VMForgeTopologyFacade: defined in URL
>   [jar:file:/Users/sagarg/vmware/vm-forge/build/libs/vmforge-0.1.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/vm-forge-api-service-0.1.jar!/com/vmware/vmforge/api/topology/facade/VMForgeTopologyFacade.class]

**Investigations so far

1. Tried using @Qualifier
2. Verified that No two instances of class files present in the Jar
3. Verified that no other class with same name in classpath**

Comment: Do you have any other inheritors of `VmForgeTopologyApiDelegate` in the code base? Do you register them as Spring Beans? If not, maybe there is some library/starter that does that. You can try to inject `List<VmForgeTopologyApiDelegate>` and see what instances do you retrieve

Comment: No I dont have multiple implementations.

Comment: Maybe you register `VMForgeTopologyFacade` twicely. For example, you have `@Component` annotation on it and also you return `VMForgeTopologyFacade` instance from `@Bean` method

Comment: if you ensure that the component bean is only register in spring environment at most once ,  and  make project  in  IntelljiJ   try to clean the cache ,  clean the class  ,recompile project ,and then try one more time .

Comment: well  , Except t above way , or  you can try to define a more closer  path   in your spring application  ann , just like ```@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xxx.xxxx"})```, i think this way could  exclude something else in you classpath

Comment: @Peng , yes closer path worked but I wonder by base path is registering bean twice. For now , used closer path to move ahead in project.

Comment: @Sagar Gandhi   .here is a not clever way to find out   where  the extra bean .  disable the bean  which you currently used  and define the ```@ComponentScan``` to scan the whole  project , and then  start up applicaion with debug model ,so that , the rest only  bean is that  which make you fell wondering for these time  .Finally Get its classpath  , find the path and  remove it .